# loop through multi-dimensional array while restarting interation from zero

Tags: php, for-loop

for example i have array like this

```
$x = array(
    array(
        array(1, 2, 3, 4),
        array(5, 6, 7, 8)
    )
)
```

and then i loop the array like this

```
$j = 0;
for($i = 0; $i < count($x[0][$j]); $i++){

}
```

if some condition occured
can i increment $j and continue/reset loop $i from 0? so $x[0][$j][0] = 5. how to do that?

currently, i tried this

```
$j = 0;
for($i = 0; $i < count($x[0][$j]); $i++){
    if(/*somecondition*/){
        $j++;
        continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: What you mean with `so $x[0][$j][0] = 5.`? (You can just set $i too -1 if the condition is to so it's 0 in the next iteration)

Comment: ups, sorry..please see updated question.

Comment: Is there a reason you have a redundant array call in the first example and then you're using `$x[0][$j]` instead of `$x[$j]`?

Comment: Secondly, from the example you provided, you aren't incrementing the array, you are looping through it.  Is that what you want to do or are you trying to add to the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want continue with `$i = 0` when a condition is `true` you can set it to `-1` when the condition is true so at the next iteration it's `0`!

Like this:

```
if(/*somecondition*/){
    $j++;
    $i = -1; //So in the next iteration when it gets incrementet by 1 it's 0
}
```

Comment: NOTE:  This is because you have `$i++` as your third argument to the `for` loop.  `$i++` will add 1 to `$i` on the next iteration.